# Is there a git command that can describe the current state as "branch/short_commit_hash"

Tags: git, github

Is there a git command that can describe the current state as "branch/short_commit_hash". I know this is possible in two seperate commands (one for branch and one for the short commit hash), but is the a specific command that can do this?

Thanks,
Evan

Comment: If you need one command, you could wrap the two commands in a bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git show --format="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)/%h" -s
master/53baf63
```